# Index a matrix using two equal-length vectors for row and column indices

Tags: r, matrix, subset

Imagine you have a 5x5 matrix and want to select values using two equal-length vectors, one representing the index row and the other representing the index column:

```
m <- matrix(1:25, ncol = 5)
R <- c(1, 3, 5)
C <- c(2, 4, 4)
```

The desired output here is a single vector of of `6` (row 1, column 2), `18` (row 3, column 4), `20` (row 5, column 4).

The best I could come up with was:

```
diag(m[R,C])
```

But this constructs a matrix of size `length(R) * length(C)` and so is slow if R and C are long.

How do you do this?

Comment: I tried a couple different `apply` solutions, and your solution with `diag` is considerably faster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cbind(R, C)` for indexing with `[`:

```r
m[cbind(R,C)]

#> [1]  6 18 20
```

Answer (score 2):

using `mapply`

```
mapply(function(r,c) {m[r,c]}, r = R, c = C)
# [1]  6 18 20
```

creating a matrix for indices.

```
m[matrix(c(R,C), ncol=2)]
# [1]  6 18 20
```

Comment: Much slower than OP's solution

Comment: It seems faster to me on a matrix of 5x5 and index vectors of length 10,000

Comment: The solution with a matrix for the indices is brilliant

Comment: someone may have a better solution. wait for some time, compare them and see which one is the best of all. then accept the solution.

Comment: I might have spoke to soon, I think it depends on how you time it. Do you do many iterations, grow the index vectors, or grow the matrix? If you have a small matrix and large index vectors then this seems faster

Answer (score 1):

Another option is

```
M[do.call(cbind, list(R, C))]
```